# using FTS3 Enabled SQLite

Tags: ios, sqlite, fts3

I have some doubts in using FTS3 Enabled SQLite. As this link suggests, [SQLITE FTS3](http://sqlite.org/fts3.html) I can reduce the database fetch time significantly (from 22 seconds to 0.003 seconds) if I use FTS3 or FTS4 Extensions. I want to know how to use this extensions and also the difference between this and the ordinary sqlite table in terms of queries and data storage. I am already using sqlite database, but since the records are around 80000, so I want to use FTS3 now. What changes will I need to make to migrate to fts3?